# Dynamic Pivoting in Linq c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, pivot

I have below data in my linq list.

```
StatusID Count MonthYear 
======== ===== =========
   1      0     Jan 2014
   2      1     Feb 2013
   1      2     Jan 2013
   3      1     Dec 2014
   2      0     Nov 2014
   5      6     Jun 2015
```

Now my requirement is i need above list in below format. **Where MonthYear column data is not fix.** It can be any month and year data.

```
StatusID  Jan 2013  Feb 2013  Jan 2014 Nov 2014 Dec 2014 Jun 2015
========  ========  ========  ======== ======== ======== ========
   1        2          0         0       0        0        0
   2        0          1         0       0        0        0
   3        0          0         0       0        1        0
   5        0          0         0       0        0        6
```

I read lots of solution on stackoverflow and even tried my own way but i was not get success. Below is code which i tried last.

```
var pvtData = new PivotData(new[] { "StatusID", "MonthYear" }, new SumAggregatorFactory("count"));
            pvtData.ProcessData(finalList, (o, f) =>
            {
                var custData = (MontlyChartModified)o;
                switch (f)
                {
                    case "StatusID": return custData.StatusID;
                    case "MonthYear":
                        return custData.MonthYear;
                    case "count": return custData.count;
                }
                return null;
            });
```

Please help me if you have any idea how to do dynamic pivoting.

[image: My datalist contain data.]

Below is my code which i implemented. but when i debug and put watch on result var it shows me error "result    The name 'result' does not exist in the current context"

```
public class MontlyChartModified
    {

        public int? StatusID { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public string MonthYear { get; set; }
    }
    List<MontlyChartModified> finalList = new List<MontlyChartModified>();
                finalList = (from x in Okdata

                             select new MontlyChartModified
                             {

                                 StatusID = x.StatusID,
                                 count = x.count,
                                 MonthYear = x.Month.ToString() + " " + x.Year.ToString()

                             }).ToList();




                var columns = new[] { "StatusID" }.Union(finalList.Select(a => a.MonthYear).OrderBy(a => a.Split(' ')[1]).ThenBy(a => a)).ToList();

                var result = finalList.GroupBy(g => g.StatusID).OrderBy(g => g.Key).Select(g => columns.Select(c =>
                {
                    if (c == "StatusID") return g.Key;
                    var val = g.FirstOrDefault(r => r.MonthYear == c);
                    return val != null ? val.count : 0;
                }).ToList()).ToList();
```

my final result.

[image]

Comment: What is `PivotData`?

Comment: hi @IvanStoev,  PivotData is a third party DLL. But when i run above code it was not pivoting. Its shows same data as in my list.

Comment: Ok, let forget the `PivotData`. What is the format of the result that you expect? e.g. class, properties?

Comment: result is in var or class.

Comment: "result The name 'result' does not exist in the current context" means that you probably have stopped at a breakpoint outside of function where `result` is defined

Comment: no i am in same function, thats why i am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with grouping:

First, I create list of columns, sorted by year and month alphabetically:

```
var columns = new[] { "StatusID" }.Union(lst.Select(a => a.MonthYear).OrderBy(a => a.Split(' ')[1]).ThenBy(a => a)).ToList();
```

Second, results are groupped by `StatusID` and for each group I create List of values for each `MonthYear` column:

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(g => g.StatusID).OrderBy(g => g.Key).Select(g => columns.Select(c =>
    {
        if (c == "StatusID") return g.Key;
        var val = g.FirstOrDefault(r => r.MonthYear == c);
        return val != null ? val.Count : 0;
    }).ToList()).ToList();
```

Input list is defined as follows:

```
 var lst = new List<MontlyChartModified>()
        {
            new MontlyChartModified(){StatusID = 1, Count = 0, MonthYear = "Jan 2014"},
            new MontlyChartModified(){StatusID = 2, Count = 1, MonthYear = "Feb 2013"},
            new MontlyChartModified(){StatusID = 1, Count = 2, MonthYear = "Jan 2013"},
            new MontlyChartModified(){StatusID = 3, Count = 1, MonthYear = "Dec 2014"},
            new MontlyChartModified(){StatusID = 2, Count = 0, MonthYear = "Nov 2014"},
            new MontlyChartModified(){StatusID = 5, Count = 6, MonthYear = "Jun 2015"},
        };

class MontlyChartModified
{
   public int StatusID { get; set; }
   public int Count { get; set; }
   public string MonthYear { get; set; }
}
```

result is `List<List<int>>`

Comment: thanks for helping me. I implemented your code but when i run the code there is no data in "result" variable.

Comment: There isn't much difference. Skip my `MontlyChartModified` class, fill `lst` with your data and it should work just fine.

Comment: please check my post once again. what i have been done and what error i found.

Comment: i found issue that we take "val" as a var so its scope is finish in one iterative. may be thats why we are not getting values in result list and its shows it emply.

Comment: Hello i am able to get answer using your code. May be there was a some issue yesterday. Now i have one query that do i able to add my MonthYear name as a column name? i mean "2 2010" as a column name. i added my result on above please look into it.